# How can I make new arrays for each respective element inside of my object which consists of four arrays total to dynamically generate a week forecast?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I am back again! I am almost done with the same project from which my most recent question is also derived. I have hit a huge bump in the road. Pretty much, I am trying to make a 7 day forecast display in my app now. Something like these:

[image]

[image]

Then, I have an object which contains four arrays each with seven elements, which makes the information that I need for a 7 day forecast. The object is like this:

[image]

I know that I could just manually add 7 cards into the  where the forecast will be, but I thought to try and generate them with one definition rather than defining 7 cards manually. My first problem in this is that I'm not sure at all how to make new arrays which would consist of four elements, being each respective element from each array. Taking the [0] element from the above example, I would essentially want it like this and seven of them. The elements are in order 'time', 'weather_code',  'temperature_2m_min', and 'temperature_2m_max':

```
daySpecs: [ "2023-12-09", 3, -12.9, -10]
```

This is the code that I have so far (rough draft, of course) which I could repeat to use and manually make 7 cards:

```
<div className='weather-forecast'>

        <div className="card">
          <h3>{datesWeek[0]}</h3>
          <p>Temperature: {temperaturesMinWeek[0]}</p>
          <p>Weather: {wmo[weatherCodesWeek[0]]}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <h3>{datesWeek[1]}</h3>
          <p>Temperature: {temperaturesMinWeek[1]}</p>
          <p>Weather: {wmo[weatherCodesWeek[1]]}</p>
        </div>

        </div>
```

This is the part which I would like to find a way to dynamically generate. You could say that there are two problems in this question. I have spent quite a long time to try and figure this out and I am getting a little distressed about this and I couldn't find anything online that would be similar to or the same as the issue that I'm having. I hope that I'm not wearing out my welcome to this site just yet, but this posed as a more unique issue and I figured that there's no harm in asking. Thanks so much in advance for anybody that could provide assistance. To be honest, I still need to eat today and I hope that you guys understand what I'm asking or can maybe tell me the best way to do it. On the contrary, if you would even tell me that making each card manually like in my code example is already an optimal way to do it, that would be quite a ride. I really just need another set of eyes on this and hope that you folks understand.

Please let me know if more of my code would be needed for this, however, a lot of my code for this project can be found in my previous question too.

EDIT: I have been requested to post some code, so I will just put all of it, as it is easier than putting portions:

App.jsx:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import "./App.css";
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import wmo from "./wmo.js"

function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const hourlyTemperaturesOneWeek = weather.hourly?.temperature_2m;
  const [isFahrenheit, setIsFahrenheit] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function getWeather() {
    axios.get('https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=65.01&longitude=25.47&current=temperature_2m,weather_code&hourly=temperature_2m&daily=weather_code,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min&timezone=auto')
      .then(response => {
        setWeather(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  }, []);


  const hoursOneWeek = weather.hourly?.time;

  const currentTemperature = !isFahrenheit 
  ? weather.current?.temperature_2m 
  : (weather.current?.temperature_2m * 9/5) + 32;

  const currentWeatherCodeLabel = wmo[weather.current?.weather_code];

  const weatherCodesWeek = weather.daily?.weather_code;
  const temperaturesMinWeek = weather.daily?.temperature_2m_min;
  const temperaturesMaxWeek = weather.daily?.temperature_2m_max;
  const datesWeek = weather.daily?.time;
  const sevenDayForecast = weather.daily;

  const date = new Date();
  const day = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][new Date().getDay()];

  const todayDate = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  const hours = date.getHours();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();

  const formattedDate = todayDate + ' ' + getMonthName(month) + ' ' + year + ', ' + hours + ':' + minutes;

function getMonthName(month) {
    let monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    return monthNames[month - 1];
}

  console.log(formattedDate);
  console.log(hourlyTemperaturesOneWeek);
  console.log(hoursOneWeek);
  console.log(currentTemperature);
  console.log(date);
  console.log(day);
  console.log(wmo);
  console.log(currentWeatherCodeLabel);
  console.log(weatherCodesWeek);
  console.log(temperaturesMinWeek);
  console.log(temperaturesMaxWeek);
  console.log(datesWeek);
  console.log(sevenDayForecast);


  const temperatures = isFahrenheit 
  ? hourlyTemperaturesOneWeek.map(temp => (temp * 9/5) + 32)
  : hourlyTemperaturesOneWeek;

  const tempUnit = isFahrenheit ? '°F' : '°C';

  useEffect(() => {
    Highcharts.chart('weather-chart', {
      title: {
          text: 'Temperatures (' + tempUnit + ')'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Temperature (' + tempUnit + ')'
          }
      },
      plotOptions: {
          series: {
              label: {
                  connectorAllowed: false
              },
              pointStart: date.setHours(2,0,0,0)
          }
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'Temperature (' + tempUnit + ')',
          data: temperatures,
          pointInterval:  3600 * 1000
      }],
      responsive: {
          rules: [{
              condition: {
                  maxWidth: 500
              },
              chartOptions: {
                  legend: {
                      layout: 'horizontal',
                      align: 'center',
                      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                  }
              }
          }]
      }
  });
  });

  const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const responsiveHeight = (350 / viewportHeight) * 100;


  return (
    <div>
      {loading === true && !weather ? <p>Retrieving weather data. Please wait.</p> : null}
      <div className='flex-container'>
      <h1 className='weather-label'>Weather</h1>
      <div className='content-box' style={{height: responsiveHeight + 'vh'}}>
          <h2 className='current-weather-title'>Current weather</h2>
          <div className='current-temperature-label'>
              {Math.round(currentTemperature * 10) / 10 + ' ' + tempUnit} 
          </div>
          <div className='current-datetime-label'>
            {currentWeatherCodeLabel}
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
              {day + ', ' + formattedDate}
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      {weather ? (
        <><div className='weather-line-chart' id='weather-chart'>
        </div>
        <button className='toggle-button' onClick={() => setIsFahrenheit(prev => !prev)}>Toggle Temperature Unit</button>
        <div className='weather-forecast'>

        <div className="card">
          <h3>{datesWeek[0]}</h3>
          <p>Temperature: {temperaturesMinWeek[0]}</p>
          <p>Weather: {wmo[weatherCodesWeek[0]]}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <h3>{datesWeek[1]}</h3>
          <p>Temperature: {temperaturesMinWeek[1]}</p>
          <p>Weather: {wmo[weatherCodesWeek[1]]}</p>
        </div>

        </div>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Styling file:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#2546ff, #2546ff, white);
}

.weather-label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  top: 0;
 }

.weather-line-chart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 3%;
  width: 60%;

  height: 50vh;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 7.8%;
}

.content-box {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 160%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.current-weather-title {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.current-temperature-label {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.125rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.current-datetime-label {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.weather-forecast {
  top: 15%;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 0fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.card {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: black;
 }

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1039px) {
  .weather-label {
    font-size: 5vw;
    transform: translate(-6vw, 0);
  }
  .content-box {
    padding: 3vh;
    top: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 400px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .toggle-button,
  .weather-line-chart {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    width: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 23.5%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  
  .weather-line-chart {
    width: 100%;
    top: calc(85% + 2rem);
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1040px) and (max-width: 1805px) {
    .weather-line-chart {
    width: 48%;
  }
}

/*@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .weather-line-chart {
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
  }
}*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 935px) {
  .weather-label {
    font-size: 4.5vw;
    top: 0;
    left: 46.3%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 412px) and (max-width: 535px) {
  .weather-label {
    font-size: 5vw;
    top: 0;
    display: grid;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 935px) and (max-width: 1040px) {
  .weather-label {
    font-size: 4.5vw;
    top: 0;
    left: 46.3%;
  }
}
export default App;
```

wmo.js (weather interpretation codes):

```
const wmo = {
    0:'Clear Sky',
    1:'Mainly Clear',
    2:'Partly Cloudy',
    3:'Overcast',
    45:'Fog',
    48:'Depositing Rime Fog',
    51:"Light Drizzle",
    53:"Moderate Drizzle",
    55:"Intense Drizzle",
    56:"Light Freezing Drizzle",
    57:"Intense Freezing Drizzle",
    61:"Light Rain",
    63:"Moderate Rain",
    65:"Heavy Rain",
    66:"Light Freezing Rain",
    67:"Heavy Freezing Rain",
    71:"Light Snow Fall",
    73:"Moderate Snow Fall",
    75:"Heavy Snow Fall", 
    77:"Snow Grains",
    80:"Light Rain Showers",
    81:"Moderate Rain Showers",
    82:"Heavy Rain Showers",
    85:"Light Snow Showers",
    86:"Heavy Snow Showers",
    95:"Slight Thunderstorm" ,
    951:"Moderate Thunderstorm", 
    96:"Thunderstorm With Light Hail",
    99:"Thunderstorm With Heavy Hail"
  }


  export default wmo;
```

Comment: What are datesWeek, temperaturesMinWeek, etc in your html code?

Comment: Why have you posted a *picture* of your `daily` Object, instead of text/code that we could easily work with?

Comment: Why don't you have an object with 'time', 'weather_code', 'temperature_2m_min', and 'temperature_2m_max', then have an array of those objects? Then you don't have to worry if one of your non-date arrays got shuffled between the source and your site? You could also query your source for a single "card" object, 7 cards, or 10 cards, or however many you wanted. I'm assuming you have access to the API to make that change? This turns your "daySpecs" into an object instead of it being an array. Also, your array being called "daily" doesn't make sense when it contains a week.

Comment: (Cont.) Sorry if that all sounds off topic, but it would allow your `map`  method (from the answer by Bhavesh Parvatkar) to have significantly simpler access to the data.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hi David! I have updated the question with a lot more clarity. I posted the code for the project so that nothing is unclear.

Comment: @computercarguy The API being used is open-meteo. It receives it like that for "daily" because I have 7 days selected as the setting for the API, as that is the task.

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar I will view your answer too. However, I have updated the question with code.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on those params.

Comment: @vaahtlnirn1, my condolences. That's a pretty useless data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to add each card for the weather. The length of all the 4 arrays will be same then we can take one array as a reference to iterate over all the arrays at the same time using index.

```
{weather?.daily?.time.length > 0 ? (
  <>
    <div className="weather-line-chart" id="weather-chart"></div>
    <button
      className="toggle-button"
      onClick={() => setIsFahrenheit((prev) => !prev)}
    >
      Toggle Temperature Unit
    </button>
    <div>
      <div className="weather-forecast">
        {weather.daily.time.map((timeValue, index) => (
          <div className="card" key={timeValue}>
            <h3>{timeValue}</h3>
            <p>Temperature: {weather.daily.temperature_2m_min[index]}</p>
            <p>Weather: {wmo[weather.daily.weather_code[index]]}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
) : null}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer worked! Sorry, my electricity happened to burn out immediately after and I had to go and buy a new fuse for my box, so that's why it took long to respond. However, I run into one problem: when I refresh my page, I get an error of "Highcharts error #13'. I am trying to figure that out now. It means that Highcharts can't find a <div> id of what to make the chart from, meaning 'weather-chart'. Upon first glance, would you happen to know?

Comment: Hi, I ended up being able to fix it after a few tries of several different methods!